# Create an event without country and state

Tags: civievent

Can I create an event without a country and state? I always get this error: State / Province does not match selected country.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a core bug. You need to first empty the selection for state/province save the form and than empty country selection and save the form.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Do you know if there is any progress on this, if you have default country and state setup, this work around does not work.